# What is meant by "dummy sentences"?

Tags: meaning

> Yes, you can easily modify pages and you can (temporarily) publish dummy sentences, and you can even (temporarily) completely destroy a page in a wiki.

In the above sentence, what does "dummy sentences" mean?

Comment: "A deliberately nonfunctional device or tool used in place of a functional one." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dummy

Answer (score 1):

A dummy sentence is a placeholder with no real meaning. You use it to test the layout of some text you're creating, like an article in a wiki.
A dummy-**something** always refers to something that has been put in place as a test, so the real "content" can be inserted later on.

If you want to know more about the why and what, [lipsum.com](http://www.lipsum.com/) seems to be a good read.

Comment: @npst A dummy sentence doesn't have to be **without** meaning. It does have a meaning, but it may not be relevant to the context or subject you're dealing with.